# Web Performance

Tags: performance

Im working on a large site, trying to decrease the load times, and I have bumped into a rather strange issue. Im using google chromes built in developer tools, and I am finding that certain images are getting hung up, and the browser is continuing to look for them. Has anyone encountered this issue before? How do I isolate what is causing this problem?

The site runs a couple of ads, is it possible this error is occurring because of ad networks?

Here is a link to the actual problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEtLA.png (updated)

Comment: Clear all `src` values from every image, then add them back in one-by-one until you see a problem occur.

Comment: You're trying to **increase** the load times?

Comment: Whoops. Sorry, its been a long day. I will re-upload a new image

Comment: Since those images have data supplied by the html directly (base64 content...) I'm willing to bet this is a bug in the developer tools. The image data was available ages earlier, and perhaps the tools just weren't prepared for inline data. Are those images actually missing? Or is this all based on this one display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea.... If not yet done, try Google's free website testing and optimization tool 'Website Optimizer'. See what it tells you.

Another idea, try accessing the site with another browser, either one, IE, Safari, or FireFox, to see if you get the same issue; if you do then it may be the server for some reason not serving those images.

One more.... To isolate further, if possible, try using only few (one or two) images in your site/pages; if these load then add one or two more images until you encounter the issue, then that image has something and you may replace that image.

Answer (score 2):

If you have not done already, use a tool like http://www.webpagetest.org/ to test your site. It will test the site from nominated locations around the world, with the browser of your choice, and you will get waterfall charts for your page.